# How to reset the "allow pc to be discoverable on this network" prompt?

Tags: networking, command-line, powershell, batch

I've searched StackExchange, StackOverflow, and Google and I'm not finding any insights on how to reset the prompt when first connecting a PC to the internet.  I've found oodles of articles here and abroad discussing "How to disable" this prompt from showing up in the first place - BUT - I'm wanting to "reset" the prompt in order to display it again as if the machine was a fresh, virgin-clean image without ever having access to the internet or network.

Otherwise - Is it correct to assume that when the user clicks "Yes" then this becomes the equivalent of running `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=”Network Discovery” new enable=Yes` from the command line?  I am wanting to make sure I do not enable a blanket set of rules by default if performing this action from the prompt does not do the same.

PS - I do understand the risks/benefits of allowing Network Discovery, but I am in a situation where our *client wants this* enabled . . .  PowerShell alternatives to change the rules are considered but unnecessary, as I know how to turn this on via `netsh` from Command Line.  If there is a PowerShell method to reset the prompt however, I'm all eyes.

Edit:
Operating System is Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019.  Thanks @Moab

Comment: Any particular Operating System?

Comment: Yes - I meant to add this to the question.  Adding shortly.  Until the edit takes, Windows 10 / Windows Server 2019 environments

Comment: Also wanting to confirm - is this type of query better suited for StackOverflow instead of here on StackExchange/Super User?

Comment: Probably Server Fault is best.>>>>https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks!  I'll post it there too.  Much appreciated sir.

Comment: http://winrollup.com/enable-network-discovery-in-windows-10-creator-edition-without-using-the-netsh-command-in-powershell

Comment: @Antony - MONEY.  That's actually pretty clean - gives a good explanation of the options.  Thanks.

I suppose then - the Prompt I'm inquiring about - this will _only_ change the Discovery for the type of network the PC Presently resides, correct?  This is the drive behind the question - I want to test it and ensure I'm only enabling it on the network the customer wants